# Connect to Google Play Games Services offline in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, achievements

I'm implementing the Google Play Games Service in Android using this guide:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Everything works fine until I'm online, but if I'm offline, at the moment of the connection, I'm getting an error.

The Achievement guide said that

> An achievement can be unlocked offline

so I would expect that, once I had successfully logged in the first time, next times I could log-in offline, unlock an achievement, and than the services would synchronize it with the server as soon as there is connection. The problem is that if I cannot log-in I don't have a reference to the GoogleApiClient object and cannot call any service. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: could you provide us with the error? thanks.

Comment: So what's the error? According to the guide you won't have to worry about. "An unlocked achievement means that the player has successfully earned the achievement. An achievement can be unlocked offline. When the game comes online, it syncs with the Google Play games services to update the achievement's unlocked state."

Comment: It should happen automatically, this isn't your worry. The Play services library probably does this already.